# warning when starting matlab and missing functions

Tags: matlab

Each time I start matlab I receive the error:

"Error using eval. Undefined function 'workspacefunc' for input arguments of type struct".

which can be fixed by typing

```
restoredefaultpath
```

and it works fine. It's getting annoying having to write that each time. Is there a way to stop this appearing each time I start a new session?

Also, I seen to be missing some built in functions. For example, I can't use the nanmean function (using R2013a). When I type

```
help nanmean
```

all works OK i.e. I see the documentation. However, when I use the function:

```
X = magic(3);
X([1 6:9]) = repmat(NaN,1,5)
y = nanmean(X)
```

I receive the error:

```
Undefined function 'nanmean' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

What is wrong with my matlab version?

Comment: could you specify your OS version, whether you are on admin privilege (Windows) and your actual default path?

Comment: Try `savepath` after `restoredefaultpath`.

Comment: You shoudl be able to check Matlabs default paths. My guess is that at some time you disconfigured that and now when Matlab opens doesnt load the path with the toolboxes and so. try to have a look and if it is not rigth, set there your desired default paths.

Comment: when I type savepaeth I get the error: 'Error using which
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\local\pathdef.m: Cannot open file: permission denied.

Error in savepath (line 24)
    outputfile = which('pathdef.m');'

Comment: I am using windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Seems like you have a problem with permissions or pathdef.m is locked by another process (maybe another matlab instance? maybe a crashed one in the background? -> check task manager or reboot). If you are not working in a restricted permission accound on windows try starting matlab in admin mode (rightclick->Run as administrator) and then resore & savepath. Another issue might be a bad command in startup.m if that file exists - it is executed each time at startup of matlab (try `open startup.m`).

Comment: Turns out that whoever was on this machine before me had tried to alter the pathdef.m file, they had tried to add some additional paths in there. After running in administrator and removing these lines, all works OK. Still have an issue with nanmean though.

Answer (score 0):

Restore to the default path and save it once to have a clean path.

Answer (score 0):

this is an accepted answer in mathworks.com and worked for me.

> I had the same issue. The supports sent me the answer below. My issue was number 2 and now Matlab works.
>
> The "error using eval" can occur due to 2 reasons:
>
> A permissions issue with "pathdef.m" The presence of Lucid Logic
>   VirtuMVP software To troubleshoot this, please check the following:
>
> 1. If Lucid Logix VirtuMVP is not installed:
>
> Then this is a path related issue that is oftentimes caused by not
>   having the necessary permissions to the MATLAB folder. Specifically,
>   this issue can be caused by not having the necessary permissions to
>   the "pathdef.m". For Windows, setting the owner of the pathdef.m to
>   Everyone and giving Everyone full control will resolve this issue for
>   all users. Execute "which -all pathdef" in MATLAB to find the file
>   location.
>
> 2. If you do have Lucid Logix VirtuMVP installed:
>
> Then the VirtuMVP entry in the PATH environment variable will need to
>   be removed ("C:\Program Files\Lucidlogix Technologies\VIRTU MVP 2.0"
>   or any other form of VirtuMVP). This product (or at least some
>   versions of it) is known to be incompatible with MATLAB. The
>   incompatibility may only impact 64-bit installations, if this issue
>   still exists.